# General integer solutions of the equation $a^{2} = (b+c)^{2}$?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations

So I wonder if there is any know result about the general form of the integer solutions of $a^{2} = (b+c)^{2}$. A class of particular solutions is readily available, the class of all triples $(a,b,c)$ of integers such that exactly one of $b,c$ is $=0$ and $a=c$ or $a=b$ accordingly.

Comment: $a = \pm (b+c)$

Comment: @user420261, Thanks; I guess I would like to know if there is a further investigation.

Comment: @EricClapton $0=a^2-(b+c)^2=(a-b-c)(a+b+c)\,$ should suffice.

Comment: @EricClapton I really doubt it

Comment: Given any integer $b,c$, define $a= \pm(b+c)$ and we get two triples (unless $b+c=0$ for which only one triple) $(a,b,c)$.                                                   I am not sure, is this what you wanted to know ?

Answer (score 2):

This really isn't the toughest class of Diophantine equation known.
Of course $a^2=(b+c)^2$ iff $a=\pm(b+c)$, so we have parametric solutions
$(a,b,c)=(t,u,t-u)$ and $(a,b,c)=(t,u,-t-u)$.